# Opencart downloadable products not showing after payment

Tags: opencart

I am looking for assistance to allow downloadable products  (mostly jpg and pdfs graphics) on my opencart site.   I am able to upload files by `Catalogs->Downloads`, and set products with a downloadable file, however when I make a purchase of one of these downloadable products, I keep getting the statement;

> "You have not made any previous downloadable orders!"

after payment is complete.  Hence, I am unable to get to the point of being able to download the product after payment.   I have Stripe installed as a payment gateway.

Through `system->settings->options`, I have set order status to "pending" and complete order status to "pending." Ideally, I would like to have downloads available immediately after purchase.

I am using OpenCart version 2.6.2.  I would greatly appreciate any assistance in this topic.

Comment: Formatted the text to make it a little more readable

Comment: Thanks, do you have a suggestion for the OpenCart issue stated above?  I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: There's no OpenCart version 2.6.2, go to admin / extension / payment / edit your payment module / Order Status must match complete order statuses that you selected on system / settings.
If you want to see download links in success page, take a look at this commercial extension I wrote before: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=30910

Answer (score 0):

When you make the order status as "complete" in sale->orders, it will be available for download. otherwise in the payment extention we need to set "complete" as default payment success.